# Framework7 Cordova app launch modal from modal

Tags: html-framework-7

I am developing a Cordova based hybrid site using Framework7.  I would like to launch a confirmation modal prompt from within a picker prompt but the second modal does not display.

I added modalStack:false to my Framework7 declaration as I thought that was the fix but it did not appear to do anything.

The workaround I have now is using a generic HTML prompt which works but is not as attractive as using the framework7 modals.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug appears to have been resolved in Framework7 v1.4.  Once updating to that version (and modalStack: true) the modals were successfully displayed.